# Start uploading files on command button click

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, multifile-uploader

I'm using jsf 2.2 PrimeFaces 6.0 and i implemented a solution to upload files using "fileUpload" component of PrimeFaces. The problem that the user can upload files on the repository even when the demand is not validated.

I'm searching help in order to start uploading files depending on commandButton click.

Here the interface of my project and the `commandButton` in green color:

[image]

Here the XHTML code :

```
<p:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{imageUploader.handleFileUpload}" process="@this"
        label="Ajouter" uploadLabel="Télécharger" cancelLabel="Annuler"
        mode="advanced" auto="false" sizeLimit="10485760" multiple="true"
        fileLimit="10" fileLimitMessage="Maximum 10 images"
        dragDropSupport="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
        invalidFileMessage="Format de fichier non valide" invalidSizeMessage="Taille maximum 10 MB"
        onstart=""/>

<p:commandButton update="@form"
                 style="background:#6FDC6F;color: #FFFFFF;float:left"
                 action="#{demandeBean.doAddDemandeBtAdmin()}"
                 value="confirmer demande">
<p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Êtes-vous sûr?"
           icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>
<p:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{imageUploader.handleFileUpload}" process="@this"
        label="Ajouter" uploadLabel="Télécharger" cancelLabel="Annuler"
        mode="advanced" auto="false" sizeLimit="10485760" multiple="true"
        fileLimit="10" fileLimitMessage="Maximum 10 images"
        dragDropSupport="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
        invalidFileMessage="Format de fichier non valide" invalidSizeMessage="Taille maximum 10 MB"
onstart=""/>

<p:commandButton update="@form"
                 style="background:#6FDC6F;color: #FFFFFF;float:left"
                 action="#{demandeBean.doAddDemandeBtAdmin()}"
                 value="confirmer demande">
<p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Êtes-vous sûr?"
           icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>
```